# What are these strange characters in wifi-menu and alsamixer?

Tags: terminal, alsa, locale, ncurses

I have a fresh install of Arch.

When I run `wifi-menu` or `alsamixer`, both of which I think use `dialog`, the display in the shell is not correct.  The border, for example, is drawn with the wrong characters.  I hope that makes sense.

What causes this and how can I fix it?

EDIT:
I found another symptom of the problem.  I was moving some files, and I got this error message:

```
mv: target È/home/korgan/wavfiles/*È is not a directory
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: here is the output of `locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
```

...and so on, until

```
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Fix [your locale](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale).

Comment: @jasonwryan My locale is set correctly.

Comment: Please show us what it is set to,what is the output of `locale`?

Comment: @terdon I've added it to the question.

Comment: Alsamixer does not use `dialog` but plain `ncurses`. If the line-drawing characters do not work, your locale or terminal are wrong. See the [FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#problems_display).

Comment: What terminal emulator are you running this in? Do you get the same symptoms in other terminal emulators (xterm, rxvt, gnome-terminal, konsole, …)?

Comment: @Gilles I'm not using an emulator.  This is all tty1 stuff.

Answer (score 0):

By "tty1", you mean a Linux virtual console.  The unexpected characters in the error message from `mv` are the separate bytes of UTF-8 encoding, but printed when UTF-8 mode is not turned on.  For instance, `È` is octal 200, the second byte of UTF-8 for both [U+2018](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2018) and [U+2019](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2019).

The Linux console can be switched into UTF-8 mode with an escape sequence, or using `unicode_start`

Further reading:

- [7.6. Configuring the Linux Console](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.3/chapter07/console.html)
- [2. Display setup](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Unicode-HOWTO-2.html) (Unicode HOWTO)
- [Unicode in a tty?](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/2uh3mm/unicode_in_a_tty/)